# Python Dictionary - Find min key where value is equal to

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary I would like to find the minimum key where value[1] is equal to a a specified string.

```
somedict = {'1': ['110', 'A'], '3': ['1', 'A'], '2': ['3', 'B'], '4': ['1', 'B']}
mindict = min(somedict.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(0) )
```

This gives me `('1', ['110', 'A'])`

I would like to further filter this by finding the min key where value is 'B'

to give me the result  `('2', ['3', 'B'])`

How would go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a generator expression filtering your items first:

```
min((i for i in somedict.iteritems() if i[1][-1] == 'B'), key=itemgetter(0))
```

The generator expression produces elements from `somedict.iteritems()` where the last entry in the value is equal to `'B'`.

Note that there is a risk here that no items match your filter! If that could be the case, make sure you catch the `ValueError` thrown by `min()` when passed an empty sequence. If you are using Python 3.4 or newer, you can specify a default to be returned for that case:

```
min((i for i in somedict.iteritems() if i[1][-1] == 'B'),
    key=itemgetter(0), default=())
```

which would return an empty tuple if no items have a last entry `'B'` in their value.

Demo:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> somedict = {'1': ['110', 'A'], '3': ['1', 'A'], '2': ['3', 'B'], '4': ['1', 'B']}
>>> min((i for i in somedict.iteritems() if i[1][-1] == 'B'), key=itemgetter(0))
('2', ['3', 'B'])
```

Comment: Wouldn't your code also work without specifying the key in this case?

Comment: @Axl: you mean the `key` function? In this case (where the dictionary keys are unique) it can indeed be omitted altogether to give the exact same outcome.